# How to put format code the right way in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I try to learn Python via LPTHW (Learn Python The Hard Way), on the ex05 (its about format code), the code that he give isn't working, I need to use different code to get the same result.

I already tried deleting the parentheses, give space between f and the double quote.

At last I use the %  (%s and %d) not the f  (f"bla bla {bla}") one

What LPTHW expect is the first code to give the same result as the second one, yet it give me invalid syntax. There's no way the computer wrong right?

So what is the problem? Because when I try to find this problem, no one have the same problem as me.

I'm sure I type it right, because after that I tried to copy the exact code from the page and it still not working.

Comment: Formatted string literals were [introduced in python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498). If you're using python 2.7 as the tag indicates then you'll have to use the old methods.

Comment: thx, sorry for the dumb question